# CDS LIKE filter from view parameter

Tags: abap, cds

How to create a CDS that select all `KUNNR` from table `KNA1` that `Customer Number` starts for example with `A%`.

I could use `LIKE` in the where clause but the `RHS` of the condition have to be static. It should depend on **the input parameter** from CDS.

Is it possible to do it with CDS?

Comment: is it ABAP CDS or HANA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options.

1. You get rid of your CDS input parameter handling and move the logic to ABAP. Write your OPEN SQL select on your CDS with like statement.
2. Use [CDS Table function](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abencds_f1_define_table_function.htm) and [AMDP](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenamdp_functions_abexa.htm) by pushing the `like` statement down to HANA native. Just follow my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115660/sap-gateway-odata-service-with-long-string/48151792#48151792) here.

Hope it helps.